# Can I tell Visual Studio to kindly keep its ugly meta files away from my source directory?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Short version: I want Visual Studio 2010 to save the solution and project files to the default "My Documents" directory, while regarding my *actual* project directory on Dropbox as the place to put source files.

---

I know I can "Add Existing Item" from the project menu, but that's hardly an acceptable solution as I have to manually create absolutely every file I'm to work with in VS from explorer. I've tried adding my project folder to the project, but that just resulted in VS lying to my face:

[image: Illustration of VS lying to my face]

Is it possible to ***actually*** separate Visual Studio's fugly meta files from my project directory? If not, what would be the best workaround?

I might have to do my C# in Vim because of this...

---

**NOTE:** I know C++ projects has the "Add Filter" function, which appears to do almost exactly what I want, but I'm working with C#.

Comment: Why don't you just use "make"? You can put anything wherever you want :)

Comment: @paulsm4: How do you mean? Could you add an answer with more details? I don't exactly see how "make" is related to this question in any way :P

Comment: Please consider removing random complains and repalce them with actual descriptin of what you don't like (bin/obj folder, *.csproj files, something else). It is clear you are not happy with something and have an answer to some problem... but it is not very clear what the problem is.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: My entire question is in the first line of the post, and that line alone should be enough for somebody to answer the question. I'm not unhappy or angry, what you're noticing is probably just bad attempts at sarcasm/humour :P

Comment: I see. If you have non-Express VS it may be easier to create throwawy projects using "File->New project->From exisintg source". (assuming you have you own build system you should not need to worry about .csproj files).

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround

Create a symlink from the actual project folder in Dropbox to Visual Studio's project folder, e.g:

```
C:\Users\tomas>mklink /J "...\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testing\Journal\journal" "...\Dropbox\Projects\cs_testing\journal"
Junction created for ...\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testing\Journal\journal > ...\Dropbox\Projects\cs_testing\journal
```

Then *add the symlink* to the project as an "External Item". Now Visual Studio thinks it's being devious and adding all new files to its own project directory, but they are actually ending up in my Dropbox.

### Drawbacks

- Every item added to the project must be put in the symlink subfolder.
- Items automatically add themselves to the namespace "<project>.<subfolder>.*", so on my case an added class was automatically called `Journal.journal.JournalForm`.
- It's tedious to do this for every project.

There are probably more, but I just discovered this workaround. I'll edit this answer later if necessary.